MongoDB starting then crashing
I was recently forced to remove and reinstall MongoDB on my web server, which is a VM running Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS. Before I erased all of the previous MongoDB files, I copied the data directory /var/lib/mongodb to a backup directory, /var/lib/mongodb_backup_force. When I first redownloaded MongoDB, everything started and ran fine. However, upon copying the data files from the backup directory back to /var/lib/mongodb, restarting, and running sudo systemctl status mongod, I get the following errors:
mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2024-12-24 20:51:26 EST; 12min ago
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
    Process: 29193 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=14)
   Main PID: 29193 (code=exited, status=14)

Dec 24 20:51:26 rapid-1662.vm.duke.edu systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Dec 24 20:51:26 rapid-1662.vm.duke.edu mongod[29193]: {"t":{"$date":"2024-12-25T01:51:26.863Z"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":7484500, "ctx":"-","msg":"Environment variable MONGODB_CONFIG_OVERRIDE_NOFORK == 1, overriding \"processManagement.fork\" to false"}
Dec 24 20:51:26 rapid-1662.vm.duke.edu systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=14/n/a
Dec 24 20:51:26 rapid-1662.vm.duke.edu systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

I've tried running the following commands to change permissions:
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb, sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock, sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb/*, and I've tried deleting the file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock. But to no avail.
When I consult the logs, I see An incomplete repair has been detected! This is likely because a repair operation unexpectedly failed before completing. MongoDB will not start up again without --repair. However, running mongod --repair fails with: Failed to start up WiredTiger under any compatibility version. This may be due to an unsupported upgrade or downgrade. I would appreciate any guidance on how to resolve this and get MongoDB running again.
Here is my /etc/mongod.conf file:
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
#  engine:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1


# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

#security:

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:


Update:
Just for context, the reason why I uninstalled and reinstalled MongoDB in the first place is because I stupidly executed the following commands without understanding what I was doing:
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-server_6.0.19_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-mongos_6.0.19_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-database-tools_100.10.0_amd64.deb

These, along with sudo apt -f install and sudo apt autoremove crashed the mongod instance that had been running via systemctl. I copied the data directory after the crash.

Did you use the same version of MongoDB? Did you stop mongod before you made copy of the files? Why did you delete the data folder when need to reinstall the MongoDB?

@WernfriedDomscheit I did make sure to reinstall the same version of MongoDB, version 6.0.19. The mongod instance had crashed before I made the copy of the data files. I deleted the data folder because I was following Claude's instructions. Stupid to do that without knowing what I'm doing, I know. But I am where I am now.

I fear, that is looking bad. Do you have any other backup?

@WernfriedDomscheit Not of the database itself. Luckily it's a small project and most of the data gets exported to CSV files soon after it's generated, so I'm not losing anything too crucial. I guess this has been a learning experience for me about not executing thoughtless -f commands.

Yes, "crucial" and "no backup" are quite contradicting though.
